# Extract title from PDF document in PHP via URL

Tags: php, pdf, extract

I need to extract the title of pdf documents from a (direct) url, so I will receive urls like:  http://somepagehere/something/something.pdf, and I need to extract only the title of this pdf document without the need to download the entire document.

I see that Zend Framework has something similar to this feature with:

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($pdfFilePath);
$title=$pdf->properties['Title'];
```

However, how do I do this in regular PHP, and how do I do so with only a url (not needing to download the entire document)? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to extract the title in the document itself (rather than the name of the PDF file), you'll need a plugin to handle that unfortunately -- it can't be done in regular PHP (easily). However, there's a lot of plugins to choose from, and your usage may make one more applicable than another:

- ApacheFOP
- dompdf
- FPDF
- html2ps
- mPDF
- PDFlib
- TCPDF
- wkhtmltopdf
- Zend_Pdf

As for actual title extraction, you're bang-on with the approach; after loading the entire PDF (which unfortunately you have to do), you need something like:

```
$title=$pdf->properties['Title'];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for basename()?

```
echo basename($pdfFilePath);
```

Will return:

```
something.pdf
```

Comment: No, not quite, basename will extract the name from the url only, which is a last resort solution, but what i would like is to extract the title property of the actual pdf, take this example: http://alex.smola.org/drafts/thebook.pdf  , here, basename will return only "thebook", but the title of the document is "AnIntroductiontoMachineLearning - thebook"...

Comment: In that case, the answer is no - you need to download the document and use a library to extract the title.